# Calling OA Page from custom JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, oaf

I'm trying to launch a custom OAF page from a custom JSP. Although the OAF page is loading fine and functionality is also working correctly, but there is drastic change in the look and feel of the OAF page. FOr eg: Go/Clear buttons are displayed as rectangles. Also, for LOVInput fields, the Quick Select is coming as an hyperlink rather than Image that we see normally.

I'm using Oracle 11i and Jdev 9i.

I have registered my OAF page through AOL function, and calling using javascript from my custom JSP.

I have tried looking at various sites but mostly they deal with launching of OAF page (which i already have done). 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/571687?start=0&tstart=0
https://community.oracle.com/thread/388873?start=15&tstart=0

My issue is with the difference in look and feel of the OAF page. It is working fine in JDev.

[Image showing Go and QUick Select buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj3TR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by updating the profile option "Oracle Application Look and Feel" value at User/Responsibility level as "Browser Look and Feel".